# How to Fix Masking for Separate RGB Node

Tags: shader-nodes, masking

Newbie here, I'm trying to follow a tutorial and encounter below problem.
I am unable to mask properly. If you see the SEPARATE RGB gives a gray output in G for the stem.
Whenever I try to mask the stem, it mixes up with others.

[image]

First, I have set up the TOP and the RIDGES using 'SEPARATE R' as the influence factor for Mix Shader . It gave me below:

[image]

Using the 'Separate B' as influence factor for the Mix Shader and just rearranging the connections. But the RIDGES are visible when using this, so I have used 'SEPARATE R' to move forward.

[image][image]

Now, when I attempted to mask the STEM of the mushroom using 'SEPARATE G', I am unable to do it correctly. The STEM texture mixes up with the other texture that it made it not visible.

[image]

Since the SEPARATE RGB have calculated different shades of black, I am having issue on masking. How can I fix the masking using SEPARATE RGB? Or what is the better approach here?

This is the paint image that I have done:

[image]

Here is the file: [image]

Comment: your mask is full black in the file attached here. You should paint it (appropriately to the uv map) in either r, g or b for each part of the uv map.

Comment: Apologies for that @lemon , Im trying but I am unable to attach it to the .blend file.

Comment: I try an answer, but it could be wrong without this mask texture... tell me...

Comment: Yes I have included the image in the main post.

Comment: The TOP = [1.000000, 0.014897, 0.020143, 1.000000]
The RIDGES = [0.014239, 0.004859, 1.000000, 1.000000]
The STEM = [0.522476, 0.118687, 0.016875, 1.000000]

Comment: If top (orange part?) is a mix of full red and partially green and blue, the result should be a mix. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes.
In the tutorial, the lecturer have used mostly S= 1 V= 1 and then the Hue he selected different colors.
I'm not sure if I should use only colors that is following that order when I need to do MASKING.
So I went and just pick a color having different combination on HSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A close up on the mix shader nodes:

[image]

The first one on the left:

- If red, this is top
- Else, this is ridge

The second one, on the right:

- If green, this is stem
- Else, this is either top or ridge (depending on the previous mix shader)

So you need:

- Red for top
- Green for stem
- Other (blue, or eventually, simply black) for ridge

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this @lemon. 
Somehow I now understand that I can only use Red, Blue and Green in the image paint to dictate the masking.
What I was doing before is to copy whatever color I gave in the ColorRamp, and use the same in the image paint.